# Data Structure that can use different indexes

Tags: java, data-structures

I am wondering if there exists a Data type/structure in Java that would allow a user to use different indexes. So it would be like a hash map (e.g. `HashMap<String, Integer>`) but instead of just using a string as the index, it could instead allow a user to use either a String or, for example, a Float, where either or could be used. For example:

```
<"Hello", _> -> 123
<"Hello", 10.5f> -> 123
<_, 10.5f> -> 123 

<"World, _> -> 456
```

etc.

I've tried creating a custom object but found that it needed to override the "HashCode" function so it didn't work.

Comment: You can use `HashMap<Object, Integer>` so the "index" can be everything

Comment: Good job making an attempt and learning about hashCode()/equals() contract. You can still use a Map if the Key objects state is final and always has the same **type** of values. I.e a String and Float.

Comment: So this means you would always need both the String and Float present? You could have either or ?

Comment: It looks like you are wanting to look up a value by *either* a key of type String *or* by a key of type Float.  If so, have you considered just using two separate maps - one keyed by String and the other by Float?  Especially as it looks like you don't have both in all cases (from your examples).  Aside: using a Float as a key to a map is a bit weird as you'd have to look up *exactly* the float value that was put into the map in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The convention would be to create a separate data structure with the new, **specific** index instead.

This means that (in Java) you now have to store your data twice, but there may be use cases in which this is more preferable.

Alternatively and in practice, designs/needs for multiple data structures to index on different keys have usually meant that someone wants a relational database as opposed to anything in Java, and that could be the cleanest approach out there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to avoid a relational database but it seems like it could be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

A dirtier approach would be to stringify and concatenate all possible keys, e.g:

```
float number = 10.5f;
String key = "Hello" + number;
map.put(key, 123);
```

A more cleaner solution would be to design a class that would be a key in a hash map. In that case you will need to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` - this is required due to HasmMap implementation. Please see the following article: [Design good key for hashmap](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/hashmap/design-good-key-for-hashmap/)

Comment: The problem is some times either the float or the string may not be present, so I needed to have the ability to omit one of them and still hash to the same item.

Comment: In that case you should define your own class to be the key.

Comment: Re "The problem is ...".  You can make this work with just a Map<Object,Integer>.  You'll just have to `put()` the value into the map with two keys e.g. two calls to `put()`.  The map *will* work when you retrieve with either of the keys used.  (Granted you lose the type safety on the key i.e. the compiler won't stop a third key type being used as well as String and Float.)  If you want to constrain what can go in the map you can hide the map in a custom class which has type-safe methods: `put(String,Integer)`, `put(Float,Integer)` - even maybe `put(String sKey, Float fKey, Integer value)`.

Comment: BTW when *reading* from a map with `get()` there is no compiler checking on the key used.  This is because (check the Javadocs) the signature is `Map.get(Object key)`.  This was necessary when generics were added to Java to avoid compilation failures in existing code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-